# Gradient vector explanation (please help)

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I'm trying to explain how to use Lagrangian multipliers, through an example.

I start in this way:

> Understanding how Lagrangian multipliers work can be done through a simple example.
> Consider the function:
> $$ f(x,y) = -2x^2-3y^2 + 3$$
> The constraint equation will be defined as the following plane:
> $$ c(x,y) = x + y = 1  $$
> Using a Lagrangian multiplier, we can find the highest point which lies both on the function and the plane.

The intersection line between the plane and the function $f(x,y)$ is graphed in the following plot in red:
[image: plot]

My question is:

In this graph, the gradient vector (arrows in blue) for the function $f(x,y)$ shows the direction of steepest ascent of the function. But what does the gradient vector of the intersection line (arrows in orange) point towards? Highest gradient of $f(x,y)$ (and not increase in height) ?  - and in a way that its perpendicular to the intersection line?

Also: is the fact that the magnitude of the gradient vectors I drew are slowly decreasing as it approaches the top of the paraboloid correct?

Thank you for any help. I am a highschool student writing a paper about calc. of variations, so my knowledge is very very basic (so please explain in detail if you have time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Vectors**

The gradient vector is the direction in which the function increases the most.

The blue gradient vectors, indicates the direction to move, if you want to increase the value of $-2x^{2}-3y^{2}+3$. Since we wish to maximize the function, we want to follow these blue vectors.

The red/brown gradient vectors, indicate the direction to move, if you want to increase the value of $x+y$. Since the constraint requires $x+y$ to be constant, we cannot follow these red/brown vectors.

**Understanding Lagrange Multiplier Method**

Now, when you use Lagrange Multiplier method, you will see that the blue and red/brown vector align at the maximum point location.

An interpretation is: at the maxima, you can no longer increase the value (by following blue vector) without violating the constraint (by following red/brown vector).

**Remarks**

The gradient vector should lie on the $x-y$ plane. Here is a picture of the contour line of the objective function (the ellipses) and the constraint (the line).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Nonetheless I have a question remaining: why are the red/brown gradient vectors perpendicular to the intersection line? (or are they?). Since they are on a plane, isn't there no direction in which the function increases the most? Or is it because the ratio between $x$ and $y$ must stay the same?

Comment: The arrows in the picture is NOT the gradient vector. The gradient vector should lie on the $x-y$ plane, not 3D vectors. Nonetheless, if you follow the constraint gradient vector, you will violate the constraint i.e. you will move away from the plane. For example, you may end up in the $x+y=2$ plane or others, depending on how far you follow the vector

Comment: Ok thanks. Are the gradient vectors normal to the plane? Or are they on the plane ( a bit like shown in the picture?) ? If they are normal (following them would lead to moving away from the plane); are the other gradient vectors (in blue) incorrect as well? - because for the Lagrangian multiplier to work, both need to be parallel if I understand well.

Comment: Am I in fact completely incorrect since I am not referring to contour lines? (I would appreciate not doing so to not introduce too many terms in my paper) - is there a way to represent the gradient vectors on the 3d graph?

Comment: Since you're doing 2D function, then you better use contour lines plot. Since the gradient vectors only live in the 2D plane. I add a picture. Point $A$ is the location of the maxima, there you see the two vectors are parallel.

Comment: Thank you thats awesome! One last thing: how can the $3D$ gradient vector of the function be translated to the $2D$ plane? Is it only the combination of the $x$ and $y$ components of it that are shown (excluding the $z$ component)?

Comment: You obtain them from the partial derivative of the function / constraint. For the function, the gradient is $-4x\hat{\mathbf{i}}-6y\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ and for the constraint, $1\hat{\mathbf{i}}+1\hat{\mathbf{j}}$

Comment: Oh ok thank you. The gradient vectors I drew in blue are also wrong then, since they are on the same 2-d plane (and not tangential to the function). Do you think that if I change my functions and constraint in terms of 3 variables it would be easier to understand since I can show everything on a single graph? Or is the added complexity too much?    Anyways thank you a lot for the clarifications.